# Error Handling for NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsxmlparser

I am in the midst of building a new project from my old files. I forgot to copy over my configuration files and of course it does not work.  I use `NSXMLparser` to read the configuration files but I am not reporting the error back correctly.

What is the proper way to detect a file access error with `NSXMLParser`?

I am initializing the `NSXMLParser` with a bad URL. The initializer returns a valid object.

When I call  `[xml parse]` it returns `FALSE` indicating an error.

But the `[xml parserError]` method returns `null`.

I don't see a good coding sequence to detect a file access error.

As requested, the code used:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
{  // Does not print with missing file
    NSLog(@"Location File Error %@", parseError) ;
}


-(id) initWithURL:(NSURL *) url // For my class
{
    self = [super init] ;
    if (self)
    {
       xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url] ;
       xmlParser.delegate = self ;
       if (![xmlParser parse])
       {
            NSError *error = [xmlParser parserError] ;

            NSLog (@"Error parsing '%@'\n%@", url, error) ; // Error is null
       }
    }
    return self ;
 }
```

Comment: Please add code for what you have done.

Comment: can you validate the URL before passing it to NSXMLParser?

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the methods on `NSXMLParserDelegate` to identify your error?  (Unless you want to validate the URL you are  passing to the parser *a priori*.)

An short, and functionally-incomplete example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Foo:NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSXMLParser *parser;
@end

@implementation Foo

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
    NSLog(@"Error - %@",parseError.userInfo);
}

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Foo *f = [Foo new];
        NSURL *u = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://badurl.alan"];
        f.parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:u];
        f.parser.delegate = f;
        [[f parser] parse];
    }
}
```

Prints the following to the console:

> 2014-03-28 05:33:11.082 Untitled[2521:507] Error - {
>       NSXMLParserErrorColumn = 36;
>       NSXMLParserErrorLineNumber = 95;
>       NSXMLParserErrorMessage = "StartTag: invalid element name\n"; }